# Fixed-size UI Layout pane changes size in IE 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) plug-in, and I'm seeing that a fixed-width pane changes its width after reducing the window height. I'm seeing this only in IE 9 (when running with a [Microsoft VM](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)).

```
var myLayout = $('body').layout({
    applyDefaultStyles : true,
    closable : false,
    resizable : false, // <-- fixed size
    west__size : 200 // <-- fixed size
});
```

If the height is large, everything looks fine:

[image: Fine]

After reducing the height, the west pane width has reduced (even more than the width of the vertical scrollbar), while the vertical div remained in the same place:

[image: Issue]

Any ideas how to fix this issue? Adding `myLayout.sizePane("west", 200);` improves the look, but doesn't fix the issue.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/getvictor/2xE5f/

Answer (score 0):

You can force the correct size for the `west` pane by changing the size and changing it back again.

```
myLayout.sizePane("west", 201);
myLayout.sizePane("west", 200);
$(window).resize(function() {
    myLayout.sizePane("west", 201);
    myLayout.sizePane("west", 200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pTD2H/

This is not a good fix. If the height of the pane changes for other reasons (like re-sizable textarea), the issue will show up again.